Receiving Twilio messages from a shortcode in a webhook instead of phone number
I have managed to set up my Twilio account (and a Flask server) and while following along the How to Create a SMS Conversation in Python tutorial I'm receiving the response message from a shortcode instead of my assigned Twilio number (see below).
I would like to receive messages from my Twilio assigned number and not from a random shortcode. Is there a setting in the Twilio console to achieve this? (Other users have posted similar questions, but so far I haven't found any solution to this.)
I'm able to send and receive messages and the webhook is properly configured, but when I receive the message, it is from shortcode 50000 instead of my actual Twilio number.
SMS Response from webohook
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

That is most likely related to the messaging route you imply when you send a message from a certain country code to another one. Which country codes do your sending and receiving numbers use? And have you tried using number from the same country?

Thks @IObert, indeed I'm using a Twilio US local phone number (+1 251 XXX XXXX) as the sender and my phone is a MX local phone number (+52 552 XXX XXXX). I have not tried using a Twilio MX local number to send messages from the same country (MX), but I will certainly try, I reached out to Twilio support and was told that Mexico-Local-SMS numbers are not available, but they provided me with several options, such as a Mexico - Short Code - SMS type, I will try with that one to see if it works. Thks again!

Yes, then it seems to be the same situation as here. I'm glad support could help you.

Summarizing the comments above as an answer:
This is likely related to the messaging route used when sending messages between different country codes. You should try using numbers from the same country and consider using a shortcode available for their country. Twilio support suggested trying a Mexico - Short Code - SMS type for the specific case mentioned.
There's more context in this answer.
